# Copying Files One by One with Pauses Between Files

Tags: bash, terminal

I want to be able to copy big tar files (100gb each) one by one, and with user action required (press enter to continue to next file) between files. As you can see I used to find to populate a list of `.tar` files.

I get this error:

> *cp: ./script_v_1_working: No such file or directory*

```
destination="$HOME/Desktop/NEW"

array=(`find * -iname "*.tar"`)

for val in ${array[@]}; do
    cp $val $destination
    read -n 1 -r -s -p $'press enter to continue...\n'
done
```

Thank you in advance for your help !

Update:

I ended up using this code:

```
destination="$HOME/Desktop/NEW"

for files in *.tar ; do echo copying "$files" ; cp "$files" "$destination" ; read -n 1 -p "Press any key..." ; done
```

Comment: Quote all your variables....

Comment: Why did you tag AppleScript ?  Please don't tag your posts with unrelated tags.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `read -n 1` to wait for the user to press any key. So if you wanted to copy all files in a directory to a target directory you could do something like this

```
for file in *.tar; do
    echo "copying" $file
    cp "$file" "$destination"
    read -n 1 -p "press enter ..."
done
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: thank you Lukas P , turns out that spaces in filenames are a problem.

Comment: You wouldn't quite do it like that.  `ls` doesn't produce reliably suitable output for piping into other commands, and will, of course, include directories. The OP is looking for `.tar` files, so you'd do this: `for f in *.tar ; do cp "$f" "$destination" ; read -n 1 -p "Press any key..." ; done`. And well done for editing the question to quote your variable, which was going to be my second point.

Comment: [Why *not* parse `ls`?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/128985/why-not-parse-ls)

Answer (score 0):

As you said in a comment, spaces are a problem. When you construct the array, all spaces act as separator, that's why you are getting the "not found" errors, because you are trying to process partial file names.

You should start by generating a proper list of files:

```
mapfile -d $'\0' array < <(find * -iname "*.tar" -print0)
```

In this command, you are telling `find` to zero-separate the results and then feeding it to `mapfile` to store everything in `array` by interpreting the zero as the separator of records.

Now, you can process that list, which now is properly tokenized, with the rest of your script. But beware of spaces! You must not allow the shell to do its usual processing on the file names, so you should quote all your vars:

```
destination="$HOME/Desktop/NEW"

for val in "${array[@]}"
do
    cp "$val" "$destination"
    read -n 1 -r -s -p $'press enter to continue...\n'
done
```

Comment: thank you Poshi - will have to look into mapfile on macOS, agree that formating is key

Comment: It's not a MacOS thing, it's a bash builtin. If it is not available in your bash version, a loop alternative can be written.

Comment: Just wanted to add that `$'\0'` is the same as `''` in this case.